# PHP How to set dynamic folder path

Tags: php

I want to set dynamic path for folder for example if user use ubuntu then path will set as ubuntu directory `(var/www/)` and if user use windows system then root path will be set as window's folder like`(xampp/htdocs/project)`

Comment: Yes, right when user use ubuntu then set as per ubuntu  or else as per window

Comment: `var/www` most likely is _not_ the correct path, but `/var/www` is. You need to take a look at the differences between absolute and relative paths. And most likely you will find that when using relative paths you have no more need to detect what absolute path your scripts are working under.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; // This  to get root working directory

echo $abs = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/project_directory/'; 
// This is to add your current working directory folder to  root directory
?>
```